# Using Just with flatMap produce Failure mismatch. Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I have such code

```
func request(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    return Just(request)
        .flatMap { request in
            RequestManager.request(request) // returns AnyPublisher<Data, Error>
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

and I'm getting compile error:

> Instance method flatMap(maxPublishers:_:) requires the types
>   Just.Failure (aka Never) and Error be equivalent

And it's clear, because `Just` has `Never` as `Failure` and `.flatMap` requires  `Error` as `Failure`, so `Never` != `Error`

I see 2 approaches:

- using *right* Publisher, instead of `Just`, but I didn't find good candidate for this.
- using some operator like `.mapError`, `.mapError { $0 as Error }`, but I'm not sure that it's great idea.

Any ideas how to handle it?

**UPDATE:**

it makes more sense to use

```
.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
```

or

```
.mapError { $0 as Error }
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is special operator `setFailureType(to:)`. You can override failure type to whatever error type you need.

```
func request(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    return Just(request)
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .flatMap { request in
            RequestManager.request(request) // returns AnyPublisher<Data, Error>
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/3343941-setfailuretype

Comment: `.setFailureType(to: Error.self)` does not work in Xcode 15.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `.mapError()` on the Just output, it will change the type to include `Error`, but that closure will never be called (so I wouldn’t worry) — this is what I would do unless someone has a better idea.

Normally, the `Self.Error == P.Error` on flatMap makes sense, as you can’t just ignore errors coming from Self.  But, when `Self.Error` is `Never`, you can ignore them and produce your own errors.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer certainly works it's pretty verbose. I stumbled on an alternative syntax using [Result<Success,Failure).publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3344716-publisher) that is somewhat more succinct:

```
Result.Publisher(.success(request))
```

(Note that in this case I'm depending on Swift to be able to infer the error type, but you might need to declare it explicitly: `Result<URLRequest, Error>.Publisher(.success(request))`)

Comment: Alternatively, `Result.success(request).publisher`

Comment: What version of Xcode and/or Swift did this work on?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 6 you should use `(any Error).self`, not `Error.self`

```
func request(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    return Just(request)
        .setFailureType(to: (any Error).self)
        .flatMap { request in
            RequestManager.request(request)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```